# can ActionServerWrapper use a dynamically set SMACH state

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just discovered ActionServerWrapper which seems to be the right choice because I need to execute and abort a smach statemachine though ROS messages.

But I have a long list of statemachines and only one can run at a time. It makes most sense to create just one ActionServerWrapper, which in the "Goal" message takes the name of the state to execute.

But the [introduction tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/Wrapping%20a%20SMACH%20Container%20With%20actionlib) shows an ActionServerWrapper where the SMACH state is set in the constructor. Can I change the main state later, just before execution?

BTW: The link at the bottom of [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/Wrapping%20a%20SMACH%20Container%20With%20actionlib#Getting_The_Goal.2BAC8-Result_Messages_Into.2BAC8-Out_Of_The_Contained_State), referring to the ActionServerWrapper documentation, is dead. Where do I find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270600/can-actionserverwrapper-use-a-dynamically-set-smach-state/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2017-09-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made it work by subclassing ActionServerWrapper and overriding execute_cb.
Then I can set the relevant state machine dynamically in the  execute_cb before calling the original  ActionServerWrapper.execute_cb.

Action server source:
http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/smach_ros/html/python/smach_ros.action_server_wrapper.ActionServerWrapper-class.html

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2